# Bug ao ler csv por requisição http (WebService)

Tags: java, web-service, restful, csv, http-request

estou com problemas para ler um arquivo csv por meio de requisição http. Seria um webService RESTFul que recebe um csv e utiliza o seu conteúdo. Eu ja tentei lê-lo de diferentes formas, com opencsv, JavaCsv.. Enfim, o bug que estou tendo é que simplesmente ao passar o arquivo por requisição http os readers não reconhecem a quebra de linha '\n' e o arquivo acaba ficando como se estivesse uma linha só. Em todas essas formas eu testei setar na "mão" o delimitador ',' e a quebra de linha '\n', sem sucesso. As vezes que obtive sucesso, foi passando o csv em forma de Base64 e depois convertento ele dentro do serviço, mas não gostaria que meu cliente precisasse converter o arquivo antes de enviar. Outra forma foi trocando a quebra de linha '\n' por ';', mas isso ja é fora do padrão e o cliente teria muito trabalho para setar. Se alguém ja passou por isso antes, por favor compartilhe a sua experiência. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Alan tem algum código para exemplificar? o formato csv é bastante simples, ele apenas possui uma separação das colunas por ponto e vircula ";" sendo assim "valor1;valor2;"

Comment: Esta questão esta melhor formatada aqui no stackOverflow em inglês:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188028/bug-reading-a-csv-file-from-an-http-request-webservice .